# mysql multiple substrings in one field

Tags: mysql

how to look for substrings in MySQL field? I use

```
SELECT
  id,
  substring_index(substring_index(code, 'Hex stringValue="', -1),'"', 1),
  code
FROM test
WHERE code LIKE "%Hex%";
```

So simply I have in field code for example:

```
<body>
   <example1>
      <highHex stringValue="fff"/>
   </example1>
   <example2>
      <smallHex stringValue="ccc"/>
   </example2>
</body>
```

So when I will run my code it will give me just for example:

```
ID | Hex
1  | ccc
```

and I want it to be like:

```
ID | Hex
1  | fff
1  | ccc
```

And when there will be no field Hex I want it to ignore that row.

Comment: Doesn't directly address your question, but why are you storing data in XML as opposed to building the hierarchy in the database (making querying much easier)?

Comment: I have no idea, it was created that way and can't be changed. Probably some genius created this.

Comment: Is this going to be a one time thing? Or run consistently? I recently had to do something similar, and did the processing in Python, converted it to a CSV and imported it into the new database structure. MySQL has two functions for XML handling, but they don't seem to be as helpful with your structure https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/xml-functions.html

Comment: If the xml structure it's standard maybe you can found a workaround else I think that you should process the rows in your code or better change the way data are saved

Comment: It won't be a one-time thing. I will have to run it sometimes 10 times sometimes none. And I can't create a new database. Let's say I will have 600 rows in my database, almost all fields will have encrypted substrings and I have to find some values in that database. So my idea is to extract substrings with id and decode them so I can look for that field by id.

I wish I could rewrite database... ;/

Comment: @Thou xml will always have at max 1 highHex and 1 smallHex tag?

Comment: @TheOni
That's the problem it won't It will have sometimes multiple fields of the same type, sometimes none. If it would be like you write I would be a lot easier :) I was thinking about using some programming language but available is gcc, python and bash -_- and I write most in C#....

Comment: Are `highHex` and `smallHex` the only tags you are interested in?  Can you have, for example, `middleHex`?

Comment: @PM77-1 Let's say its just field <Hex stringValue="some_code"/> to simplify it. They are multiple in one field or it can be one or none. No pattern here.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941001/2055998

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired output, this is not a good match for a SELECT statement on the current table.

Consider creating a derived table that has one row per line of XML. Or consider writing a script in python or similar, rather than making SELECT do all the heavy lifting with self-joins or related craziness.